# variable is not reachable in qweb report?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I am trying to create a qweb report and I used the following snippet however I get an error that **"global name 'partner' is not defined" while evaluating**

```xml
<t t-foreach="partners" t-as="partner">
    <t t-set="p_inovices" t-value="list( l.number for l in docs if l.partner_id.name == partner )" />
</t>
```

Comment: Could you add better explanation that you want to do? Could you add some more code? What would you like to print in the report?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using **[ ]** instead of using **list()** & everything worked fine

```xml
<t t-foreach="partners" t-as="partner">
    <t t-set="p_inovices" t-value=" [ l.number for l in docs if l.partner_id.name == partner ] " />
</t>
```

also I'd like to mention that if I didn't use list comprehension it does work fine, as following:

```xml
<t t-foreach="partners" t-as="partner">
    <t t-set="p_inovices" t-value=" list ( partner ) " />
</t>
```

I think it is because qweb foreach is working a little bit different